# Callback for ping command is missing "ctx" parameterDiscord.py cog's command error

Tags: python, discord.py

I am trying to make discord bot with `discord.py` library. So, I made two files - **main.py** and cog named - **auto-reply.py**. When I start **main.py** file everything is still ok, but when I try to use command from cog **auto-reply.py** it says

```
Ignoring exception in on_message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\owner\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 690, in _parse_arguments
    next(iterator)
StopIteration

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\owner\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 343, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\owner\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 979, in on_message
    await self.process_commands(message)
  File "C:\Users\owner\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 976, in process_commands
    await self.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\owner\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 939, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\owner\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 855, in invoke
    await self.prepare(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\owner\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 789, in prepare
    await self._parse_arguments(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\owner\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 693, in _parse_arguments
    raise discord.ClientException(fmt.format(self))
discord.errors.ClientException: Callback for ping command is missing "ctx" parameter.
```

My **main.py** file:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=">")

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'{bot.user} has connected to Discord!')


@bot.command(name="hi")
async def hello_world(ctx: commands.Context):
    await ctx.send("Hey!")

bot.load_extension("cogs.fun.auto-reply")

bot.run("OTA2MTY5Nzk2MDI5MjAyNTAz.YYUuYw.Ox1q8_397DU9FWYHtuS101f_wns")
```

And **auto-reply.py** file:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=">")

class autoreply(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    @bot.command(name="ping")
    async def yo(ctx: commands.Context):
        await ctx.send("pong")

def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(autoreply(bot))
```

I use python 3.9 and discord.py 1.7.3. I will be happy if you guys can help me :D

Comment: Functions/methods within a class always take `self` as the first argument (unless they're static/class methods, but in this case, they're not).